# Warning while clicking on my wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, warnings, callstack

I'm creating a e-commerce website with WordPress locally. When I click on my hamburger menu it gives me this error:

> WARNING: USE OF UNDEFINED CONSTANT ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE - ASSUMED 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' (THIS WILL THROW AN ERROR IN A FUTURE VERSION OF PHP) IN C:\WAMP64\WWW\WORDPRESSPROF\WP-CONTENT\THEMES\OCEANWP\INC\HELPERS.PHP ON LINE 1699

and the menu item below

****Informations****

I'm using Woocommerce

[image]

Comment: We'd need to see code to assist. Seems like `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` is somewhere in your code but not defined. Maybe a scope issue.